# Regex to capture substring between quotes

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I have the following piece of code that works: (A standard text string)

```
($txid) = $content =~ m/ start (.*) stop /;
print $txid;
```

And the following piece of code that doesn't: (A string with quotation marks)

```
($txid) = $content =~ m/<input name="transactionid" value="(.*)" type="hidden">/;
print $txid;
```

I'm guessing the problem is being caused by the quotation marks. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: The issue is verly likely *not* with quotation marks. (a) Don't parse HTML with regexes, this is bound to create fragile solutions. (b) What input do you have? Show us an example.

Comment: [`"It's not working"`](http://tlp-perl.blogspot.se/2013/06/its-not-working.html) is not a very good way to describe your problem.

Comment: The input is way to large to put on here, it's a webpage of HTML. The first one I just did a string " start hello stop " which returned "hello" correctly. The second one just returns an empty variable. I have checked and $content is filled with the correct data, I just need to grab the value of the hidden field "transactionid".

Comment: Perhaps you should come up with a sample input which contains the relevant data that *is* possible to paste into your question. Ideally, you should write a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) so that people can jump right in, run your code and answer your question. That is, if you want fast and good answers.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `*` quantifier is "greedy", which means `(.*)` will match everything it possibly can. To restrict it such that it matches as little as possible, i.e. only until the next double-quote that occurs in the string, add a `?` to it, thus:

```
($txid) = $content =~ m/<input name="transactionid" value="(.*?)" type="hidden">/;
```

Assuming the value of the `value` attribute contains no escaped double quotes, this will produce the result you're after.

(Of course, in cases where there *are* escaped double quotes, there is no regex which will reliably extract just the string of interest and nothing else. This is why people tell you not to use regexes as your sole tool for parsing balanced text. On the other hand, given the simplicity of your purpose here, you'll probably get away with it -- but for anything, and I mean *anything*, that requires HTML or XML handling that's even slightly more complex than this, use an XML parser.)

Comment: @user1796225 Glad to be of help. That said, the warnings you've been given about using regexes to parse HTML are the result of aggregate years of swearing, hair-pulling, and generalized misery, and you would be extremely well advised to abide by them. You're only getting away with it here because you have a very simple problem; if your requirement were even slightly more complex, I'd have given you an HTML::TreeBuilder example instead. Of course you're welcome to ignore this advice, but you do so at your peril.

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your advice. Like you said, it is one simple task and it's the only time I need to parse HTML in the entire piece of software. In the future if I'm every parsing HTML I will keep this advice in mind. :-)

Comment: You should use match every character; you should use match all but the delimiter: `([^"]*)`